# PHP remove jQuery $.cookie()

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

During a login script, I create a cookie using the $.cookie() jquery plugin.  I set the cookie like so:

`$.cookie('mbr_user_key', details, { expires: 365, path: '/' });`

`details` is given above it, and the cookie sets just fine and this gives it an expiration of 1 year.

I've created a script with PHP that uses the stored cookie to get the last-logged-in ip address (stored when the user logs in) and checks it against the current IP address.  If it sees that the two IP addresses are different, it is supposed to require the user to log in again.

The script that checks the ip address in the database against the current ip address works fine, the only snag is when it comes to removing the cookie if they mismatch.

I'd like to do this in PHP of course.  Here's the script:

```
if($user_ip == $user_ip_db && $user_proxy == $user_proxy_db){
    $access = "allow";
} else {
    unset($_COOKIE['mbr_user_key']);
    setcookie('mbr_user_key', '', time() - 3600, '/');  
    $access = "deny";
}
```

but this is not working.

This works...(But I feel like this is very dirty)

```
if($user_ip == $user_ip_db && $user_proxy == $user_proxy_db){
    $access = "allow";
} else {
    ?><script>$.removeCookie('mbr_user_key');</script><?PHP 
    $access = "deny";
}
```

Either way, this script that tries to remove the cookie is running in the head as basically the very first thing.  There are no echos above it, there's only the stylesheets and javascripts linked above it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Going to take a guess, because I've never used jQuery.cookie, but is the domain the same? Perhaps your Javascript file is located at a different location than your script which makes the cookie not available.

What do you get when you do `var_dump($_COOKIE['mbr_user_key']);`?

Comment: Ahh, so they have to be coming from the same page? or at least folder?  I get this when I do the var_dump `"string(14) "ntg-599d52-412"`  I don't know what string(14) is, but the other jumble is the semi-hash cookie)